# Open Collapse Tab in Hover in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having Collapse Panel in Bootstrap which is opening on a click on the title of the tab. I am trying to figure out to open using the hover of the mouse on the total width of the tab but I am not getting it. Below is the code of the single tab which is close by default.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color:#039;"> 
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#039;">
         <a  class="nodecoration panel-title lead" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-814345" href="#panel-element-566205">Software Development</a>
    </div>
    <div id="panel-element-566205" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="background-color:#039; color:#fff;">
        <div class="panel-body" style="border:none; font-size:14px; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0;">
            We work for almost all web based application, database-driven systems, mapping and geo-spatial applications, and large content managed websites
            <br /><br /><p style="font-style:italic; font-weight:700;">Find out more</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If we change the css class from `class="panel-collapse collapse"` to `class="panel-collapse collapse in"` then the tab is open. Could you please let me know how to achieve this.

**I GOT THE ANSWER BUT WORKING ONLY BY HOVER ON THE TITLE NOT ON THE TOTAL WIDTH OF THE TAB. THE CODES ARE BELOW**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter.collapse', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            href, target = $this.attr('data-target') || e.preventDefault() || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')
            ,
            option = $(target).hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : "show";
            $('.panel-collapse').not(target).collapse("hide");
            $(target).collapse(option);
    })
});
```

Can we make this to work by hover on the full width ??

Comment: The answer [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228447/bootstrap-3-collapse-on-hover) should get you on the right track.

Comment: After hover if the tab open, you want it to keep it open or only keep it open till the mouse over the tab and as soon the mouse leave the tab area it auto close itself?

Comment: hello shehary, Yes i want it to open only until the mouse on the tab.. please let me know..

Comment: @WebDesigner if you use the @ sign with name i will get notified instantly but saw your message very late, any how posted the answer with 2 possible solutions.

Comment: @Shehary, Thank you dear for your suggestion. I will do like this again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this with `hover` function

```
$(".panel-heading").hover(
 function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
  }, function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
);
```

But it will close the panel as soon as mouse leaves the title header

[Fiddle with hover](http://jsfiddle.net/kLx6e52e/)

Alternate solution is `mouseenter` function

```
$(".panel-heading").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".panel-collapse").fadeIn();
    });
 $(".panel-collapse").mouseleave(function(){
       $(".panel-collapse").fadeOut();
});
```

With this the panel only close when mouse leaves the panel body.

[Fiddle with mouseenter](http://jsfiddle.net/kLx6e52e/3/)

Comment: Its wroking perfect. Thanks for your time in writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine js hover event and [collapse bootstrap methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods) as events too.
If i understood your question correctly.