# How to make columns/accordion open (or collapse) when the mouse moves over (or leaves) the panel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, panel, multiple-columns, bootstrap-accordion

I tried to incorporate solutions from experts all over but I still cannot get my columns to open when I hover the mouse over the panel.

What I'd like to achieve is:

1. When the mouse is moved to any panel area (it does not have to be over the actual anchor text), the panel body automatically opens (and subsequently all other panels close which the code already does).
2. When the mouse leaves the panel area the panel body automatically collapses.

Please review my code and let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much for your time!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="panel-group" id="Heyaccordion">
       <div class="panel panel-default col-lg-2">
           <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a href="#collapseTopOneMore" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Heyaccordion">Box 1</a> </h4>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseTopOneMore">
              <div class="panel-body">
                 <a href="#">Boxy 1 body</a>
              </div> 
           </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="panel panel-default col-lg-2">
           <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a href="#collapseTopTwoMore" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Heyaccordion">Box 2</a></h4>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseTopTwoMore">
              <div class="panel-body">
                 <a href="#"> Box 2 body</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default col-lg-2">
           <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a href="#collapseTopThreeMore" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Heyaccordion">Box 3</a> </h4>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseTopThreeMore">
              <div class="panel-body">
                 <a href="#"> Box 3 body</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**In jscript**

```
$(".panel-heading").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".panel-collapse").fadeIn();
});
$(".panel-collapse").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".panel-collapse").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: If none of those "experts" mentioned that this sounds like a UI disaster, then I'd question their expertness.

Comment: A jsfiddle plase?

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272168/open-collapse-tab-in-hover-in-bootstrap

Especially this: http://jsfiddle.net/kLx6e52e/3/

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I did this

```
.panel-title > a {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

and the whole panel is clickable... but it still requires a click.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the collapse class that is on the panel-collapse element or even both the classes. The classes are the ones that make the panel collapsed. So asking to fade in and out wont override the collapse class. I would put an alert in the mouseneter and mouseover event just to validate that the event is raised as expected. If that work then try to add and remove the collapse class

Comment: I do not see any action from the code. It's as if the code does not exist. I then put an alert() to see the code is loaded. The alert message does pop up on refresh but none of the hovering shows up.

I forgot to mention that this code is in SharePoint as a web part along with calendar and other default constructs on the same page. Do you think there is a conflict?

Comment: So the event is hooked correctly. I don't think it will be a clash with share point but it is definitely possible.I still think it is because the 'collapse' class is present. It is the 'collapse' class which displays it as collapsed. Have you tried to remove the collapsed class when the mouse over event executes?

Comment: I am sorry. I am very new to this. Could you please show mew how to remove the collapsed class without breaking other actions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am  not 100% sure of what class to give the one you don't want to collapse (e.g expanded?) But this should remove the 'collapsed' class from the only the one that raised the event:

```
$(".panel-heading").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).click();
});
$(".panel-collapse").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Nothing happens after I put in the code. The accordion still only opens and closes when I click on it. No auto open effect when I move my mouse over the panel. Please help-

Comment: Have you tried to fire the click event on the mouse enter and mouse leave event. From your explanation it seems the click event does a toggle of the accordion. So it would make sense that the click event would solve this.